# How to login to Facebook using the sharekit API?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, sharekit, fbconnect

I am using sharekit API for sharing images into Facebook. It is working fine, but I just want to login but don't want to share image. How can we do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SHKSharer *service = [[[SHKFacebook alloc] init] autorelease];
[service authorize];
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Ole. Is it possible to add a like button using this api ?

Comment: You should accept the answer and post another question as this has really nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: Can you help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772378/getting-user-id-of-facebook-and-twitter-in-sharekit ?  Thank You.