# Getting user id of facebook and twitter in sharekit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, fbconnect, sharekit

Iam implementing facebook and twitter using sharekit for an iphone app. How can we get the user id of the logged in user so that I could send it to the server. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get facebook user information using new facebook graph APIs for sample code you can use [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1578/how-to-get-a-user-profile-with-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Step 3 of the installation for Sharekit?

> > Step 3: Filling in API Keys
>
> Most of the web services that ShareKit
>   integrates require you to use an API
>   key when connecting. An API key is a
>   unique identifer that tells the
>   service what app is making the
>   request.
>
> You have to sign up for each api key,
>   but they are all free and sign-ups are
>   quick.
>
> Locate and open the file SHKConfig.h,
>   just inside the ShareKit group in your
>   project's file list.
>
> At the top you'll find a list of
>   services that require api keys. Each
>   service has a link next to it. Follow
>   the link for each service to get an
>   api key. Fill in the api key for each
>   corresponding service within
>   SHKConfig.h.
>
> Note: Follow the comments within the
>   SHKConfig file, they provide
>   additional steps and possible
>   customizations for each service.

For the full documentation see http://www.getsharekit.com/install/ and http://www.getsharekit.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the textual user name, but if you are after the id -

Take a look at ShareKit's SHKFacebook class.
It has an FBSession member called session.
An FBSession has a FBUID which is just a typedef for long - but I'm assuming it represents some form of user ID.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the  ID's  by extending the  enum in sharetype .  add type as ID . and  when you can  share function introduce the case for ID checking .

```
- (void)getFollowers
{
    OAMutableURLRequest *oRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=%@", SHKTwitterUsername]]
                                                                   consumer:consumer
                                                                      token:accessToken
                                                                      realm:nil   // our service provider doesn't specify a realm
                                                          signatureProvider:nil]; // use the default method, HMAC-SHA1

    [oRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    //NSString *message=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"status=oh man! OAuth u almost killed me! more info at http://dev.twitter.com"];
    //[request setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
    //todo : handle for error callback
    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:oRequest
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(getListsTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:)
                  didFailSelector:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need some user info, user name etc, this problem is solved in [reborn ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit). See [FAQ](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/FAQ).