# In ShareKit, how can I get the user's Facebook user name?

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharekit

I'm using ShareKit and have verified that the user is logged in to Facebook. I want to get their Facebook user name. Here's what I tried:

```
SHKFacebook *facebook = [[SHKFacebook alloc] init];
[facebook getAuthValueForKey:@"username"];
```

The `getAuthValueForKey:` method isn't returning anything to me. How can I get their Facebook user name?

Comment: This questions was asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772378/getting-user-id-of-facebook-and-twitter-in-sharekit with no answer still *unfortunately*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Facebook Graph API for get username. Add method bellow to FBSession.m class of FBConnect package.

```
#import "JSON.h"
```

...........

```
static NSString *const kGraphAPIURL = @"https://graph.facebook.com/";
static NSString *const kFBGraphAPIUserName = @"name";
```

...........

```
// Get user name via Facebook GraphAPI.
- (NSString *)getUserNameByUID:(FBUID)aUID {

    NSString *userName_ = nil;

    NSURL *serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%qi", kGraphAPIURL, aUID]];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:serviceUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if (error != nil) {
       NSLog(@"######### error: %@", error);
    }

    if (jsonString) {

        // Parse the JSON into an Object and 
        // serialize its object to NSDictionary
        NSDictionary *resultDic = [jsonString JSONValue];

        if (resultDic) {
            userName_ = [resultDic valueForKey:kFBGraphAPIUserName];
        }
    }

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    return userName_;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm hoping to be able to use the ShareKit API to get their username, but maybe that's not possible...

Comment: here what is the kGraphAPIURL,kFBGraphAPIUserName and shows the warning           NSDictionary *resultDic = [jsonString JSONValue];
NSString may not respond to -JSONValue

Comment: static NSString *const kGraphAPIURL = @"https://graph.facebook.com/"; 
static NSString *const kFBGraphAPIUserName = @"name"; and don't forget add #import "JSON.h" at the top of FBSession.m file